# How to overwrite jQuery function for image zoom on click?

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery library that's name is `main.js`. In main.js is the following code that disables closing div when clicking inside div (clicking outside div it closes div).

```
       // Articles.
        $main_articles.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            // Close.
                $('<div class="close">Close</div>')
                    .appendTo($this)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        if (nohash) {
                            history.go(-1);
                        } else {
                            $main._hide(true);
                            nohash = true;
                        }
                    });

            // Prevent clicks from inside article from bubbling.
                $this.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

        });
```

This code works but I added inside div a img tag with attribute `data-action="zoom"` so when I click on img it needs to be zoomed. This is not working because `event.stopPropagation();` is in `main.js` from plugin. So I don't want to change original main.js library (because of feature updates). I added custom.js after main.js to put in custom.js code that overrides above function.

In short:

When I click inside div it does not close div
When I click outside div it closes div
When I click on img tag that have attribute `data-action="zoom"` it disables `event.stopPropagation();` and then library for zooming works.
When I click inside or outside div it uses `event.stopPropagation();` and closes div.

UPDATED EXAMPLE:

i have:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    <article id="myarticle">
        <h2 class="major">TITLE</h2>
        <p>jfjfjfjfjfjfj</p>
        <img src="image.png" height="484" width="655" data-action="zoom" alt="">
        <p>jfjjffjf</p>
        <div class="close">Close</div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Original code is here:
https://themes.gohugo.io/theme/hugo-theme-dimension/assets/js/main.js

And on line 312 you will see this:

```
// Articles.
        $main_articles.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this);

            // Close.
                $('<div class="close">Close</div>')
                    .appendTo($this)
                    .on('click', function() {
                        if (nohash) {
                            history.go(-1);
                        } else {
                            $main._hide(true);
                            nohash = true;
                        }
                    });

            // Prevent clicks from inside article from bubbling.
                $this.on('click', function(event) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

        });
```

So this function disables clicking inside article tag, and that is fine...but i need to enable only clicking inside article tag that have img tag with attribute `data-action`.

How to override this function to enable clicking only on img with attribute 'data-action' inside article while clicking on others elements inside article is disabled?

Comment: Please edit the example to be complete, it's missing alot of the things you are describing. For example the image and all javascript handling of that. It's hard to understand what is happening here, why do you need the stopPropagation? In which element and how is the image click-event bound? Etc

Comment: i update example above..hope anyone can help me..because i try 2days and i im unable to make it work.